# Numbers I can get by adding an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, logic, addition

I need to get a minimum number that I cant get by adding different numbers of an array. Basically if I have these numbers:1,1,1,5; I can get 1,2,3,5,6... but I cant get 4 so that is the number I am looking for. Now this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Broj_6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner unos = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k;
    int n = unos.nextInt();
    int niz []= new int [n];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        niz[i]=unos.nextInt();
    }
    BubbleSort(niz);
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.print(niz[i] + " ");
    }
    for(int br = 1;br<=10000;br++){ 
        for(k = 1;k<n;k++){
            if(niz[k]>br){
                break;
            }
        }
        int podniz [] = new int [k];
        for(int i=0;i<podniz.length;i++){
            niz[i] = podniz[i];
        }
        //This is where I will need my logic to go
    }
}

static void BubbleSort (int [] niz){
    int pom;
    for(int i = 0;i<niz.length-1;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<niz.length-1-i;j++){
            if(niz[j]>niz[j+1]){
                pom = niz[j];
                niz[j] = niz[j+1];
                niz[j+1] = pom;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So the code goes by testing each number individually from 1 to 100000 and makes a subarray of all numbers given that are less than the number itself. Now here is the problem,I dont know how to mix and match the numbers in the subarray so it can get(or not get) the desired number. When every combination is tested and there is no desired number,I will break; the loop and print i. Just to clarify,I can only use addition,and each number can only go in once

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as below:
Use two nested loops, like below to calculate the sum of different numbers:

```
List<Integer> additionList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int []inputNumbers = .... // Logic to read inputs
for(int _firstIndex = 0; _firstIndex < totalInputs; _firstIndex++){
    for(int _secondIndex = _firstIndex + 1; _secondIndex < totalInputs; _secondIndex++){
        additionList.add(inputNumbers[_firstIndex]); // only because you have 1 in the sample output
        additionList.add(inputNumbers[_firstIndex] + inputNumbers[_secondIndex ]);
    }
}
```

Then sort `additionList` and look for any missing entry. The first missing entry will be your answer,

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the whole array and then finding sum of all subarrays does solve the problem, but is costly: O(2n^2) ~ O(n^2).

More efficient way to solve this will be Kadane's Algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

What the algo does:
Start from first element and increase the array size (sub array) till you reach the sum you're desiring.

```
my_num = 1;
while(true){
  if(sum_subarray) > my_num){
    current position = new subarray;
}
```

and this subarray concept is calculated through Kadane's approach:

```
def sum_subarray(A):
sum_ending_here = sum_so_far = 0
for x in A:
    sum_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + x)
    sum_so_far = max(sum_so_far, sum_ending_here)
return sum_so_far
```

I couldn't solve the problem completely. 'my_num' mentioned here needs to be incremented from 1, and break when `my_num > max_sum`. I hope someone can add to it and make it compilable.

**Note:**

This will also take care if negative elements are present in array.